# Magento 2.4 Installation issue (setup not working)

Tags: magento2, installation

I have tried to install magento 2.4 using below commands

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition m24

bin/magento setup:install --backend-frontname="admin" \
--db-host="localhost" \
--db-name="m24" \
--db-user="root" \
--db-password="password" \
--language="en_US" \
--currency="GBP" \
--timezone="Europe/London" \
--use-rewrites=1 \
--use-secure=0 \
--base-url="http://localhost/magento/m24/" \
--base-url-secure="https://localhost/magento/m24/" \
--admin-user=admin \
--admin-password=admin@111 \
--admin-email=any@any.com \
--admin-firstname=admin \
--admin-lastname=admin \
--cleanup-database
```

It installed but when i visit `http://localhost/magento/m24/` it shows 404 not found
On `http://localhost/magento/m24/pub/` it redirects to homepage but no image & css fetch
as its all 404.

Any way to make it work ?

Comment: Did you created separate conf file? Or edit in 000-default.conf file?

Comment: It worked, as per your article for magento 2.4 pub, but now other magento setup are not accessible.
localhost redirects to the site (example.com) as per the article.

Comment: I followed same steps mentioned in your article https://www.rohanhapani.com/solved-404-not-found-after-fresh-magento-2-4-2-installation/

Comment: If you will create virtual host then it will be working on multiple instance. I already tried.

Comment: did that worked ?
instead of example.com i used magento24.com
it worked but then the other magento exisiting setup are not working.
@RohanHapani it would be helpfull if you add or update answer or your article to create multiple instance in local.
Like example.com

Comment: I already tried and then, I post my answer and article and it's working fine. Maybe something is missing from your end. I already running many m2.4.1+ instance and m2.3+ instance in my local. You can contact me on skype.

Comment: That's cool.
Actually i already had magento 2.3.3 version installed in system,
no virtual host configured (just with apache + mysql + php 7.3)
with localhost/magento233 it was working.
Then i installed magento 2.4.2 but there were issues with (404 error) then found your article & followed steps.
it worked. but localhost/magento233 redirected to new magento 2.4.2 setup.
may be because i have set DocumentRoot /var/www/html/m24/pub/.

Comment: So, i wonder now any way to access other setup also ?
may be adding old setup to virtual host.(not sure)
need some guidance on that @RohanHapani

Comment: In which file you setup /var/www/html/m24/pub/ ?

Comment: sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/magento24.com.conf

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127908/discussion-between-rohan-hapani-and-hamendra-sunthwal).

Comment: @RohanHapani i have edited /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf this file

Comment: reverting the DocumentRoot to  /var/www/html in /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf file
worked now i can access localhost

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you setup mangento, you need to point magento to `pub` directory.

Now that you are using localhost and you haven't used [virtual host](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/configure-virtual-host-on-windows-10-for-wordpress/), you need to open your project with `http://localhost/magento/m24/pub/`

For images and CSS, access your database and you need to update table `core_config_data`
execute following commands:

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET `value`='http://localhost/magento/m24/pub/' WHERE path='web/unsecure/base_url';
UPDATE core_config_data SET `value`='http://localhost/magento/m24/pub/' WHERE path='web/secure/base_url';
UPDATE core_config_data SET `value`='http://localhost/magento/m24/pub/media/' WHERE path='web/unsecure/base_media_url';
UPDATE core_config_data SET `value`='http://localhost/magento/m24/pub/media/' WHERE path='web/secure/base_media_url';
```

Flush cache at the end

Hope this will resolve the issue

Comment: I had followed this article https://www.rohanhapani.com/solved-404-not-found-after-fresh-magento-2-4-2-installation/ but now localhost redirect to the example.com
how to manage multiple magento setup with this ?

Comment: for local, instead of example.com use `.local` domains, like `m24.local`. For all other magento websites you also need to configure virtual host. After this setup your http://localhost wont work

Comment: Yes, localhoist not working it redirects to single magento setup.